# pt-table-sync usage

Tags: replication, mysql-5.5, percona-tools

There're Master (10.0.0.1, mysql 5.5.43) and only one Slave (10.0.0.2, mysql 5.5.55). Replication is set up, running and show all OK.

But `pt-table-checksum` found data differences in some tables between Master and Slave.

First - check, what will be changed: running from Master `pt-table-sync --verbose --dry-run --print --databases analiz_cli --tables export_log --sync-to-master h=10.0.0.2,u=slave_repl,p=xxx,P=3306`

gives error:

```
DBI connect(';host=10.0.0.2;port=3306;
mysql_read_default_group=client','slave_repl',...) failed: Access denied
for user 'slave_repl'@'10.0.0.2' (using password: YES) at /usr/bin/pt-table-sync line 2220
```

Same error occurs when running this command on Slave (and changing host to Master's IP. Tried using `root` user - same error.

So, the questions are:

1. If I need make Slave equal to Master - what command and from what server I need to run?
2. What's wrong with above command, why it doesn't grants access?

Comment: The Slave should have a login with only `REPLICATION CLIENT` granted.  Is that the Slave complaining?  Or is it `pt-table_sync`; it will need more permissions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is `pt-table-sync` error message. Seems it needs more grants for working. I'll check what grants are needed later.